# Lithium car battery won't jump van's battery but regular jumper cables work

Tags: battery-charger, battery-testing

Twice over the past year my wife has left something on in our Honda Odyssey. Both times I've not been able to jump start the van using a NOCO 1000Amp 12-Volt lithium battery. But, both times I've been able to jump start it using jumper cables to my other car.

Cold voltage on the battery is 12.5V

Does my battery need replacement or is the NOCO just unable to jump the van's battery?

thanks in advance!

Comment: The question isn't very clear as to what "not been able to jump start" means. One shopping website says the polarity connection does not matter. However the user manual says you must connect positive to positive. It also says "Some vehicles may require the GB40 to be connected for up to 30 seconds before starting." It also describes the controls and LED meanings.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'm afraid I may not have the technical expertise to clarify my question. When the lithium battery was connected lithium battery positive to car battery positive and lithium battery negative to ground bolt on car, the van wouldn't start even after letting it sit a couple of minutes. When I connected jumper cables to the dead battery and my other car, the van started.

Comment: One thing that confuses me about the NOCO is that it says you can recharge it in 3 hours from a USB port at 2 amps. That is only 6 amp-hours, which can supply the claimed 1000 amps for a few seconds only (although a typical car won't draw that much starting current).

Comment: it's possible your battery was completely flat and the lithium battery only partially charged it.  This would make jump starting with jumper cables much easier.

Comment: Thanks JL I think the issue was poor connection using the clamps. I switch to an eyelet adapter and the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jump starting a vehicle with another vehicle's battery, the cables, battery and alternator of the other vehicle provides a much higher current capacity (and less voltage drop) than using a portable booster device such as the lithium battery.

Note the relatively small diameter wires in the booster device compared to those of a set of jumper cables. That's the first hint that you won't get the instantaneous current/power of a set of jumper cables.

Weather Vane's reference to time is valid and I'd expect that 30 seconds is insufficient for a reasonable start. If the non-working battery is completely dead, the booster device is unlikely to start the vehicle. If the non-working battery is low and merely needs a "top-off," you'll still have to provide the luxury of time to allow the electrons to flow from the booster to the jumped-battery and settle in and get ready to work.

Cold voltage on the non-working vehicle battery is 12.5v is not surprising. If that's the voltage of the booster device, that's not going to help much. The voltage of the booster device has to be greater in order to provide the "pressure" to move those electrons to the other side.

Comment: thanks for the comment I didn't think the issue was the van battery. The info in your comment leads me to conclude the problem is the booster battery.

Answer (score 0):

Lithium battery boosters can be tricky. Don't know about NOCO, but I have a similar battery that has a considerable self-discharge that won't allow starting a car after 3-4 months of storage (I found out the hard way). Using the booster battery to charge a phone or something like before trying to start a car has understandably similar results.

Second, the temperature matters. All batteries (including the booster one) work way better at 20C rather than in 0C. If you are in the nortern hemisphere now, it's important.

Also, fully-depleted car battery may not accept quick charging so these 30 seconds are better made at least 30 minutes (the booster battery may or may not have enough capacity for these 30 munites).

I recommend getting a different booster. Mine is rated "160A" (1000A are unreasonable for these wires anyway) and easilly starts a 2.5 gas engine with its battery completely removed (don't try this at home!). It is also rated in ampere-hours and NOCO is not. Its manual doesn't impose 30s interval of pre-charging, it recommends to try starting immediately.

Comment: thanks that answers my question: the booster is the problem. The attraction to the NOCO was its size, whats the brand you have maybe its equally small?

Comment: In the battery world, "small" is not a good word. All other things equal, the bigger, the better. Mine is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIVXh_n78Ko but I am pretty sure there are better ones and I am also sure this one is sold under other brand names. This one just happened to be sold at local grocery and I got it out of curiosity. It happened to be useful. I am yet to test it on 3.8l engine (no one managed to deplete its battery to the point it won't start).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to connect the black cable to the negative terminal of the battery and not some other ground bolt on the engine block. Jumper pack LEDs indicate all is well if black connected to engine block ground, but it doesn't work.

I have a 2016 Honda odyssey. Battery has been weak recently and I have needed to jump it with another vehicle a few times. I purchased the NOCO Boost Plus GB40 with high hopes after seeing videos of completely dead cars being started with no problem. I was disappointed that it did not work on my car after several tries, even letting the lights race and charge the battery for several minutes. But, I discovered it was operator error. The negative battery terminal on my Honda Odyssey is almost completely inaccessible. My failed attempts were all when I had hooked up the battery pack with the negative terminal going to a nearby engine block bolt, the way that they recommend when you are getting a jump from another vehicle. With that configuration, the jumper pack LEDs indicate that everything is fine, but it apparently will not work that way. Once I struggled to access that negative terminal and barely got the clamp to latch on, the car started up perfectly right away.

Comment: thanks for your response dssabo. I ended up buying an accessory from NOCO, item GBC007, that connects directly to the battery terminals. This solved my problem and will solve your problem of the neg terminal being inaccessible. It also made it a bit more user friendly for my wife.

Comment: Oh. That's a cool accessory. Thanks for the heads up.